# CameraX ML KIT giving error " java.lang.IllegalStateException: Image is already closed

Tags: android, firebase-mlkit, android-camerax, google-mlkit

I want to make a real time image classifier using Google ML Kit and CameraX API. I am using Preview and Analysis of CameraX API.
It is giving error as

```
    2020-07-27 01:17:18.145 11009-11009/com.example.camerax_automl W/System.err: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Image is already closed
    2020-07-27 01:17:18.145 11009-11009/com.example.camerax_automl W/System.err:     at android.media.Image.throwISEIfImageIsInvalid(Image.java:68)
    2020-07-27 01:17:18.145 11009-11009/com.example.camerax_automl W/System.err:     at android.media.ImageReader$SurfaceImage$SurfacePlane.getBuffer(ImageReader.java:832)
    2020-07-27 01:17:18.145 11009-11009/com.example.camerax_automl W/System.err:     at com.google.mlkit.vision.common.internal.ImageConvertUtils.zza(com.google.mlkit:vision-common@@16.0.0:139)
    2020-07-27 01:17:18.145 11009-11009/com.example.camerax_automl W/System.err:     at com.google.mlkit.vision.common.internal.ImageConvertUtils.convertToUpRightBitmap(com.google.mlkit:vision-common@@16.0.0:89)
    2020-07-27 01:17:18.145 11009-11009/com.example.camerax_automl W/System.err:     at com.google.mlkit.vision.common.internal.ImageConvertUtils.getUpRightBitmap(com.google.mlkit:vision-common@@16.0.0:10)
    2020-07-27 01:17:18.145 11009-11009/com.example.camerax_automl W/System.err:     at com.google.mlkit.vision.label.automl.internal.zzo.zza(com.google.mlkit:image-labeling-automl@@16.0.0:16)
    2020-07-27 01:17:18.145 11009-11009/com.example.camerax_automl W/System.err:     at com.google.mlkit.vision.label.automl.internal.zzo.run(com.google.mlkit:image-labeling-automl@@16.0.0:60)
    2020-07-27 01:17:18.145 11009-11009/com.example.camerax_automl W/System.err:     at com.google.mlkit.vision.common.internal.MobileVisionBase.zza(com.google.mlkit:vision-common@@16.0.0:23)
    2020-07-27 01:17:18.146 11009-11009/com.example.camerax_automl W/System.err:     at com.google.mlkit.vision.common.internal.zzb.call(com.google.mlkit:vision-common@@16.0.0)
    2020-07-27 01:17:18.146 11009-11009/com.example.camerax_automl W/System.err:     at com.google.mlkit.common.sdkinternal.ModelResource.zza(com.google.mlkit:common@@16.0.0:26)
    2020-07-27 01:17:18.146 11009-11009/com.example.camerax_automl W/System.err:    ... 9 more`
```

Here I have used a TextureView and A Textview to show the classification result. I have also put .tflite model in the assets folder and insert required dependencies. My code is given below -

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private int REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSIONS = 101;

    private final String[] REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS = new String[]{"android.permission.CAMERA"};

    TextureView textureView;
    ImageButton imgbutton;
    //LinearLayout linear1;
    TextView text1;



    //automal objects

    AutoMLImageLabelerLocalModel localModel =
            new AutoMLImageLabelerLocalModel.Builder()
                    .setAssetFilePath("model/manifest.json")
                    // or .setAbsoluteFilePath(absolute file path to manifest file)
                    .build();


    AutoMLImageLabelerOptions autoMLImageLabelerOptions =
            new AutoMLImageLabelerOptions.Builder(localModel)
                    .setConfidenceThreshold(0.0f)  // Evaluate your model in the Firebase console
                    // to determine an appropriate value.
                    .build();
    ImageLabeler labeler = ImageLabeling.getClient(autoMLImageLabelerOptions);


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        textureView = findViewById(R.id.view_finder);
        imgbutton = findViewById(R.id.imgCapture);
        text1 = findViewById(R.id.textView2);

        if(allPermissionsGranted())
        {
            startCamera();

        }
        else
        {

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS, REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSIONS);
        }
    }


    private void startCamera() {

        CameraX.unbindAll();

        Rational aspectRatio = new Rational (textureView.getWidth(), textureView.getHeight());
        Size screen = new Size(textureView.getWidth(), textureView.getHeight()); //size of the screen

        PreviewConfig pConfig = new PreviewConfig.Builder()
                .setTargetAspectRatio(aspectRatio)
                .setTargetResolution(screen)
                .build();

        Preview preview = new Preview(pConfig);

        preview.setOnPreviewOutputUpdateListener(new Preview.OnPreviewOutputUpdateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onUpdated(Preview.PreviewOutput output) {
                ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) textureView.getParent();
                parent.removeView(textureView);
                parent.addView(textureView, 0);

                textureView.setSurfaceTexture(output.getSurfaceTexture());
                updateTransform();

            }
        });

        ImageAnalysisConfig imconfig = new ImageAnalysisConfig.Builder().setTargetAspectRatio(aspectRatio)
                .setTargetResolution(screen)
                .setImageReaderMode(ImageAnalysis.ImageReaderMode.ACQUIRE_LATEST_IMAGE).build();

        final ImageAnalysis analysis = new ImageAnalysis(imconfig);





                analysis.setAnalyzer(new ImageAnalysis.Analyzer() {
                    @Override
                    public void analyze(ImageProxy image, int rotationDegrees) {


                        Image img = image.getImage();
                        if (image.getImage() == null) {
                            Log.d("Null", "Image is Null");
                        } else {
                            InputImage img1 = InputImage.fromMediaImage(img, rotationDegrees);

                            labeler.process(img1)
                                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<List<ImageLabel>>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onSuccess(List<ImageLabel> labels) {
                                            // Task completed successfully
                                            for (ImageLabel label : labels) {
                                                String text = label.getText();
                                                float confidence = label.getConfidence();
                                                int index = label.getIndex();

                                                text1.setText(text + " " + confidence);


                                            }


                                        }

                                    })
                                    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                            // Task failed with an exception
                                            // ...

                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                        }


                                    });


                        }

                        image.close();
                    }
                });

        CameraX.bindToLifecycle((LifecycleOwner)this,analysis, preview);


    }

    private void updateTransform() {

        Matrix mx = new Matrix();
        float w = textureView.getMeasuredWidth();
        float h = textureView.getMeasuredHeight();

        float cX = w / 2f;
        float cY = h / 2f;

        int rotationDgr;
        int rotation = (int)textureView.getRotation();

        switch(rotation){
            case Surface.ROTATION_0:
                rotationDgr = 0;
                break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_90:
                rotationDgr = 90;
                break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_180:
                rotationDgr = 180;
                break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_270:
                rotationDgr = 270;
                break;
            default:
                return;
        }

        mx.postRotate((float)rotationDgr, cX, cY);
        textureView.setTransform(mx);
    }

    private boolean allPermissionsGranted(){

        for(String permission:REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }



}
```

What wrong I am doing here?

Comment: can you reformate your code. remove the emty lines and shorter spaces. it's hard to read. at which line do you have the error?

Comment: and which version from camerax do you use? do you use beta or alpha?

Comment: I am using CameraX 1.0.0-alpha02

Answer (score 6):

You must not close the image before it is processed. Closing the image triggers another image to be taken by the camera to be processed by your app.

**Processing takes time.** It is not immediate.

```
labeler.process(img1)
        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<List<ImageLabel>>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(List<ImageLabel> labels) {
                // Close the image
                image.close();
                ...
            }
        })
        .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                // Close the image
                image.close();
                ...
            }
        });
```

Comment: Can I use ImageProxy object in inner class ? I have tried it but it is saying to make ImageProxy final.

Comment: Yes, you will need to make it final. Nothing wrong about using it like that in an anonymous class **in your particular situation**. I'll post an update on how to make it better.

Comment: Ok sir. Thank you very much.

Comment: @SouvikSankarMitra, actually no update is required. I've been looking at my own MLKit project and understood that no improvement is required here. I use the same technique.  If the answer helped you please consider accepting it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively to repeating the image.close() within two separate listeners, you can just use the [OnCompleteListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/play/core/tasks/OnCompleteListener), which will be called regardless of success or failure after all task processing has completed. Also I added `img.close()` for good housekeeping and avoiding potential errors of similar nature.

## Errors

```java
labeler.process(image)
    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<List<ImageLabel>>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(List<ImageLabel> labels) {
            // Task completed successfully
            Log.i(TAG, "labeler task successful");
            // Do something with the labels
            // ...
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            // Task failed with an exception
            Log.i(TAG, "labeler task failed with Error:" + e);
    }
});
img.close();
image.close();
```

## No Errors

```java
labeler.process(image)
    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<List<ImageLabel>>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(List<ImageLabel> labels) {
            // Task completed successfully
            Log.i(TAG, "labeler task successful");
            // Do something with the labels
            // ...
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            // Task failed with an exception
            Log.i(TAG, "labeler task failed with Error:" + e);
    }).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<List<ImageLabel>>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<List<ImageLabel>> task) {
            img.close();
            image.close();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Each use case should be setted in different threads for avoid interference in processing.

For use cases:

- Barcode Scanning
- Text Recognition

---

```
private fun setsAnalyzersAsUseCase(): ImageAnalysis {
    val analysisUseCase = ImageAnalysis.Builder()
        .build()

    if (BARCODE_SCANNING_ENABLED) {
        analysisUseCase.setAnalyzer(
            Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()
        ) { imageProxy ->
            processImageWithBarcodeScanner(imageProxy = imageProxy)
        }
    }


    if (TEXT_RECOGNITION_ENABLED) {
        analysisUseCase.setAnalyzer(
            Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()
        ) { imageProxy ->
            processImageWithTextRecognition(imageProxy = imageProxy)
        }
    }

    return analysisUseCase
}
```

GL